# Unable to upgrade Jhipster from v6.6.0 to latest stable version 7.9.3 or beta version 8.0.0-beta.2

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry, jhipster-blueprint

I have upgraded node version to latest 18.17.0 and updated all the global npm packages available.
While I am trying to upgrade jhipster project using angular and springboot giving below errors.

ERROR! ERROR! Command failed with exit code 1: npm exec --no jhipster -- --with-entities --force --skip-install --skip-git --ignore-errors --no-insight
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm exec --no jhipster -- --with-entities --force --skip-install --skip-git --ignore-errors --no-insight
at makeError (file:///C:/Users/ASNAG5/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:59:11)
at execaSync (file:///C:/Users/ASNAG5/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/execa/index.js:201:17)
at execaCommandSync (file:///C:/Users/ASNAG5/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/execa/index.js:276:9)
at UpgradeGenerator.spawnCommandSync (file:///C:/Users/ASNAG5/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/dist/actions/spawn-command.js:24:16)
at UpgradeGenerator._generate (file:///C:/Users/ASNAG5/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/dist/generators/upgrade/generator.mjs:169:29)
at UpgradeGenerator._regenerate (file:///C:/Users/ASNAG5/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/dist/generators/upgrade/generator.mjs:187:14)
at UpgradeGenerator.prepareUpgradeBranch (file:///C:/Users/ASNAG5/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/dist/generators/upgrade/generator.mjs:370:26)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async UpgradeGenerator.executeTask (file:///C:/Users/ASNAG5/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/dist/actions/lifecycle.js:240:13) {
shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: npm exec --no jhipster -- --with-entities --force --skip-install --skip-git --ignore-errors --no-insight',
command: 'npm exec --no jhipster -- --with-entities --force --skip-install --skip-git --ignore-errors --no-insight',
escapedCommand: 'npm exec --no jhipster -- --with-entities --force --skip-install --skip-git --ignore-errors --no-insight',
exitCode: 1,
signal: undefined,
signalDescription: undefined,
stdout: undefined,
stderr: undefined,
failed: true,
timedOut: false,
isCanceled: false,
killed: false
}

upgrade application with latest version of jhipster

Comment: Have you read how jhipster upgrade works? https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/#automatic_upgrade It does re-generate your app in  "from" version and then in "to" version, it means that you cannot use a version of node that is not supported by the "from" jhipster version, you must keep same node version that you used to initially generate your project.